# Каждая цифра исходного текста заменяется второй после нее цифрой по кругу (0 – на 2, 1- на 3, 2 – на 4, …, 8 – на 0, 9 – на 1). Остальное без именений

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, сижу второй день, не понимаю как сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, условие задайте в самом вопросе, а не в заголовке. Во-вторых, вы должны привести хоть какой-то вариант решения задачи, т.к. мы не можем решить домашнее задание за вас. Мы здесь имеем право только направить вас в нужную сторону

Answer (score 1):

Переменной `text` можете присвоить свой текст

```
def main():
    text = "314TimurIsGod15926535897932384626433832795028841971"
    result = ""

    for char in text:
        if str.isdigit(char):
            digit = int(char)
            result += str((digit + 2) % 10)
        else:
            result += char

    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод программы:

```
536TimurIsGod37148757019154506848655054917240063193
```